# How to filter data through mat table without changing the data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to search through the data which I have changed using ternary operator
Here's the HTML

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="IsActive">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
              Status
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="theData(element.IsActive)">
              {{ element.IsActive === 1 ? 'Activated': 'Deactivated' }}
            </td>
          </ng-container>
```

For TS

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['FirstName', 'MobileNumber', 'EmailAddress', 'IsVerified', 'IsActive', 'action'];
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(response['Data']);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
theData(event:any){
console.log(event); }
```

I am getting enum values and I want to sort them out according to the value that I am passing in the ternary operator

The data that I am getting is

```
{
"Id": 7,
"FirstName": "Sanyam",
"MiddleName": "",
"LastName": "Chaurasia",
"AvailabilityStatus": "Away",
"IsVerified": 1,
"CreatedOn": "2023-05-12T12:39:52.073",
"CreatedBy": 2,
"Status": 1,
"IsActive": 1,
"Preference": "Default",
"DeviceId": 0,
"SendbirdAccountCreationStatus": "Success"
```

}

For IsActive the value is either 1 or 0
I need to display Activated of 1 and vice versa
When I search the searched data should be the one visible in mat table instead of the one that I am passing as the data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` field provided with your `MatTableDataSource` with a form or reactive form.

```js
// ...your component
private _filter = '';
get filter() { return this._filter; }
set filter(f: string) {
  this._filter = f;
  this.dataSource.filter = f;
}
ngOnInit() { // Or wherever you initialize your datasource
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.filter = this.filter;
}
```

The datasource's value will be lowercased and striped of spaces.

Alertnatively, you can use `dataSource.filterPredicate` function that takes a string argument (you can use a stringified JSON to be parsed in the filter predicate function) in case you want to filter on multiple fields.

Comment: The filter function is working and I have added that snippet in the above question
What I am trying to accomplish is search the visible table instead of the data table that I am passing.
Can you please take a look again?

Comment: It does work but removes everything else.
I am trying to change the search parameters for only a select few but everything gets changed and making search params for each and everyone is quite hectic. 
Please share some stackblitz code if you got my point.

Comment: Quick example for using the `filterPredicate` on a `MatTableDataSource`: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-29v82c?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: I used the stackblitz and it worked Thanks @Askirkela